# What happened when Adam Reith reached Earth?

Tags: jack-vance, planet-of-adventure

In Jack Vance’s Tschai Cycle (*Planet of Adventure*), Adam Reith, Traz Onmale, and Anacho spend four books running across the planet Tschai, searching for a spaceship to take Adam home to Earth, considered little more than a myth or a joke for the rest of the planet. Eventually, at the end of Book 4, they climb into the spaceship and sail towards Earth.

Did Vance ever indicate what happened upon Reith’s return home? I know it probably sounds silly, but all these years I have imagined what a strange reception the group would receive on their arrival at Earth; Earth had received a signal for help from a planet, First Contact, sent out their own ship to investigate which was never heard from again, then an alien spaceship arrives containing the last survivor of the Earth ship along with unidentifiable humans with the most wild of stories. Yea, I kinda want to know what happened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, but Vance never published anything further about Adam Reith's story.

That was pretty typical of his writing.  Vance seemed to favor a "one hero, one quest" format.  Once his protagonist's main goal was achieved, the story ends, even if there are expected to be more adventures in the hero's future.  Kirth Gersen, after five books and his final defeat of *The Demon Princes*, was looking for something else interesting to do with his life.  Joaz Banbeck has a working spaceship at the end of *The Dragon Masters*; so does Paddy Blackthorn in its Ace Double edition partner, *The Five Gold Bands*.  The protagonists are planning further galaxy-crossing adventures at the end of *Night Lamp*.  However, nothing was written about any of these character's further exploits.  (Vance did reuse broad settings, but in the form of new characters, having unrelated adventures set in the same cosmos—tied together by minor elements at most.  But even in that respect, I don't think he ever wrote anything else that seemed to be set in Adam Reith's universe.)

Comment: I figured that was likely the case, given I cannot recall every having seen or heard otherwise for any of his works, but I thought it was worth asking nonetheless.